# Allowing text in TextField that must follow a complex Regex in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

**I am creating a `TextField` in flutter, but I want the input to explicitly follow a regex**: `^-?\d+(\.\d+)?(-\d+)?(e-?\d+)?$` (That allows scientific numbers, in which `'e'` is used as powers of ten).

When the user enters a character that makes the input not follow the regex, the character will just not be entered and the valid input that was before remains.
How can I achieve that?

**I tried:** using `inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow()]` and other formatters, but I can only set banned or allowed characters, not a whole regex expression.

**I searched:** stackoverflow, but all answers just give that certain characters are allowed and some aren't. I haven't seen anyone validate input by a whole complex regex.